# changes to /etc/network/interfaces not working?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file

I'm trying to add 2 **virtual interfaces** which connect to 2 different routers of 2 different ISPs

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth2 inet static
        address     192.168.0.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
        gateway     192.168.0.1

dns-nameservers    8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface eth3 inet static
        address     192.168.1.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
        gateway     192.168.1.1
```

I've tried all these commands and none of them work

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo /etc/init.d/networking reload`
```

And these

```
sudo ifconfig eth2 down
sudo ifconfig eth2 up
```

I get an error :

> eth2: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

I've tried inserting `manged=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

and then restarting `sudo service network-manger restart`

When I type `ifconfig -a`

All I get is

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:4d:11:22  
          inet addr:192.168.1.90  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe4d:1122/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8027656 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20898303 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:553970620 (553.9 MB)  TX bytes:1471000436 (1.4 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1837917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1837917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:240925560 (240.9 MB)  TX bytes:240925560 (240.9 MB)
```

My Question is : How can I add interfaces `eth2` & `eth3`?

Comment: Do you inserted nic cards or you wont to make subinterface `eth0:2` and `eth0:3`?

Comment: @2707974 Edited question, I'm trying to add 2 virtual interfaces which connect to 2 different ISP routers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, if you have one nic you can add virtual interfaces on this way

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.57
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   up ip addr add 192.168.0.57/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
   down ip addr del 192.168.0.57/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1
   up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
   down ip route del 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0:1 metric 20
```

In your question `eth0` is in net range `192.168.1.xxx` and `eth3` is also in that range, meybe is enough to have only one interface in one network range?

You can add `eth0:2` on the same way like `eth0:1` if you need one more virtual interface

But this will work only in two cases.

1. your pc is connected to switch and both router is also connected on the same switch. On this way pc can reach both router
2. you router have primary and secondary ip address on interface

Edit 1

You must edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

This will open the ‘NetworkManager.conf’ file in our text editor.

Now change:

```
managed=false
```

to

```
managed=true
```

After changes reload network service

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Or if this did not work, try

`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

Comment: Could you also add a command to reload these changes.

Comment: This is what i get when i enter that in ubuntu 14.04
`stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking`  I've mentioned in the question that this did'nt work, is this another way to reload the interface?

Comment: I made the changes and ran `sudo service networking restart` and got the same error as above but on running `sudo service network-manager restart` i get this result -> http://oi62.tinypic.com/34zdfd0.jpg  the connection `eth1` is visible as `ifupdown(eth1)` but it does'nt show up on `ifconfig -a`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Today is not my day. I make mistake and now correct them. Please look again at the beginning of answer in first code and correct `eth1` to `eth0`

Comment: This is my `interfaces` file http://pastebin.com/L22HHcJ7  I ran both the above commands including `sudo ifconfig eth0 down && sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and the result when typing `ifconfig -a`  is the  same as the screenshot. wonder what's missing...

Comment: Do not use `ifconfig` use `ifup` and `ifdown`. `ifconfig` do not read `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: ah, thanks for your support, but when i give `sudo ifup eth0` I get  
`RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0`

Comment: Ah, Now it works! I had to reboot the system. Still dont know why i got that `RTNETLINK` message, . wish i could get it to work without rebooting though, Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey, an update, Removing spaces before `iface` in the second line worked! -> this is how the file looks like > http://pastebin.com/qDi6mSwR. and i had to run `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` after that. Could you please add it into your answer so it may help someone?

Comment: I correct answer

Comment: managed=true helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `eth2` will tell the system to use another adapter but you only have one. to define virtual adapters you should use `eth0:<number>`.

Try this one:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0:1 inet static
        address     192.168.0.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
        gateway     192.168.0.1

dns-nameservers    8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface eth0:2 inet static
        address     192.168.1.57
        netmask     255.255.255.0
        gateway     192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a virtual interface type the following command in your Linux Terminal
Command:
`ifconfig VIRTUAL_INTERFACE_DEVICE IP_ADDRESS netmask SUBNET_MASK up`
For example,
`ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.6 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
This will create a new virtual interface named eth0:1 and assigns the IP Address 192.168.1.6.

To Make this Virtual Interface Permenant Create a new file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1` with the following contents

> DEVICE=eth0:1
>   ONBOOT=yes
>   BOOTPROTO=static
>   IPADDR=192.168.1.99
>   NETMASK=255.255.255.0

Type `service network-manager restart` after editing to apply changes.

To Up and Down the Virtual Interface, use the following commands 
`ifup eth0:1`  and `ifdown eth0:1`

Comment: FYI for other readers: the second part of this answer (/etc/sysconfig) is applicable to Red Hat derivatives, but not Debian derivatives like Ubuntu.